# How to install an OS on a external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, multi-boot, operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Multiple OS on external hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/166709/installing-multiple-os-on-external-hard-drive)

I made a little research before coming here. And found out that I need to disconnect all internal hard drive before proceeding.
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/installing-ubuntu-to-a-usb-hard-drive/

Here's my question:

1. If I install Windows XP or Ubuntu on an external hard drive. Would it be universal? Can I use it or run it on any computer. Assuming that the bios allows you to boot from USB hard drive. Or even not because there's [PLoP Bootmanager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html) And has the considerable amount of memory and processor power to run the OS.
2. What other things to consider when installing an OS in an external hard drive?
3. Is installing in the external hard drive the same as when installing in an internal hard drive? Can I also boot multiple OS? What are the things to consider when doing this?

And if you have a tutorial there. Showing how to install an OS in an external hard drive. Please link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check these two links out

[Ehow](http://www.ehow.com/how_4814278_install-windows-external-hard-drive.html)

More detailed, ThechSpot: techspot.com/vb/topic116114.html

Comment: It really feels unsafe to be following tutorials from unreliable sources like e-how.

Answer (score 1):

With Fedora, passing `expert` to the installer will allow you to do various "expert" things such as installing to a removable drive. As long as grub is installed to the removable drive and the BIOS is capable of booting off it, you should be able to use it on any appropriately-similar machine.